# How do I issue an HTTP redirect with Perl's CGI.pm?

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I want to perform an HTTP redirect, but the way I am currently doing it isn't working. When I try redirect it just prints the status code, and the location header:

```
my $q = new CGI;
q->redirect(" http://www.google.com ");
```

Comment: What is the status code that is returned?

Comment: Erm, second line? $Dollar sign? Typo?

Answer (score 2):

Are you requiring CGI at the top?

```
use CGI;
my $query=new CGI;
print $query->redirect('http://www.foo.com');
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Is there a purpose the spaces around the URL? Depending on what the CGI library does, those might present a problem. I could see it converting your URL to %20http://www.google.com%20 which would not load correctly...

**Edit**: It doesn't seem to do anything harmful when I test it, other than being passed right through to the browser. On the other hand you are missing a `use`, a `$` and a `print` in your code -- is this the actual code you are trying, or something else?

Answer (score -3):

I figured out what the problem was, I trying to redirect after i had printed the 200 ok status, which would result in me printing the URL to the page instead of redirecting to it

Comment: This is why should post the actual code you are trying, not something different. :)